# How to select a team for a new website development project

Tags: project-management, planning, team-building

I am promoted to team lead position in my organization. Previously I was working as senior software developer or senior software engineer.

Now company want to build their own product which is a website. Requirements and technologies selection are established as well. They want to hire team for this project.

```
Senior software engineer

Junior software engineer

Web Designer (UI)

Database Admin

SEO Expert
```

I have given task to decide which team member should selected first. What I think Database Admin should hired first.

Please share your ideas so I should make my first decision accurately.

Thank you

Comment: What kind of website?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich We are building Online shoping website but with some other features.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously up to personal preference, but here's my pick. It really depends on what your role in this project is: if you perform things such as project management or technical work yourself you can get by with hiring other people. If you do not take the lead of this project from a technical perspective, I'd advise you to take the senior on first.

Also, I would imagine these people will not exclusively be assigned to this project full-time? I'm having a hard time believing that a fulltime SEO expert, DBA and designer are needed on a team with only two developers?

**Senior software engineer**

Good. Can get started on implementing basics for your project: build scripts, sandbox environment, CI-integration, authentication, minification and bundling,... Can also work on general architecture analysis based off the requirements.

**Junior software engineer**

Average. Would probably be better off working under the guidance of a senior engineer, but if your company has solid fundamentals and your project needs to be integrated into this it might work. If you have an existing build process and CI server for example a junior engineer might be able to get things configured by looking at (and learning from) previous projects. But more likely to work on easier tasks (less on fundamental architecture, more on basic CRUD-features and input screens) which can probably only be done once architecture is somewhat finalized.

**Web Designer (UI)**

Good. Can get working on the design without having any of the basic infrastructure in place. Will most likely do a lot of prototyping and wireframing and can therefore start working well before the first actual code is written. Will at some point require development to have actually started.

**Database Admin**

Average. I'm not a big fan of starting with a database schema and having the application designed 'up' from there, instead preferring to start working on the domain of the application and then adapting the database to fit that structure. Will have little work to do early on once the database design is somewhat finalized but will become more important as the project is being used to maintain the database and monitor performance as data is added.

**SEO Expert**

Bad. Will be needed more towards the end of the project, but has very little to do until some form of deliverable is available.

Comment: I think initially we should start with Senior software engineer :)

Answer (score 1):

I share @JDT 's opinions overall, but with a few tweaks

**Senior software engineer**

My personal first pick. Why? Because he'll basically be the glue between the view and the data. Good ones will typically also be able to mock up the database and the UI. This helps to clarify the requirements and identify road blocks early on. It's also a difficult to find one ...a good one.

**Junior software engineer**

Definitely not the first hire. You don't want a noob to mess up the foundations. Also, the senior should have a saying in who you hire as a junior. After all, they will be working closely together for quite some time.

**Web Designer (UI)**

Second/third. First, you want things to work, then you want to make it nice. Don't underestimate it though, because making the UI prototype early on will typically show that some features are required or should be altered. Also, it should not be underestimated. I've seen several apps where the front-end was more work than the back-end.

**Database Admin**

Second/third. At the company I work, we don't really have dedicated DB admins, it's part of developers job. I can only imagine a dedicated DB guy when there is some really heavy DB lifting. However, data is also the corner-stone of the app, so it should be done right.

**SEO Expert**

The last. Once at least the prototype is ready.

---

A last word about senior/junior. It's more about competence than seniority. They are only very loosely related.

---

**One more note**

I don't know how it works for you guys, but where I work, most people are typically cross boundaries. There are the developers which do back-end and database, and the ones which do web UI and backend. Indeed, most of the work is about connecting the dots, not working on each aspect in isolation.

Comment: I strongly agree with your opinion about DB admin. :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the senior software developer, so you have someone else to help you come up with an overall architectural design for the project. This may influence your later hires significantly.

For example, if you decided that the application was going to be heavily database-oriented, or you were going to use an enterprise-grade database such as Oracle instead of, say, MySQL, then hiring an experienced DBA would become an early priority. On the other hand, if you're writing a typical LAMP-stack website, you'll probably find that the developers you hire are familiar enough with MySQL that you decide to hire two junior devs instead of one dev and a full-time DBA. At the very least, discuss the possible team makeup during your senior developer interviews, if possible.

As for the other positions: web designer is good, although in such a small team you'd want to make sure they also had either CSS/frontend dev skills or graphic design skills. SEO expert as a full-time position in a team of 5 strikes me as very odd, unless it includes content creation for the website as well. A good senior developer will be able to have these discussions with you, especially if they have experience in online shopping websites (I assume you/your company does not?), which probably have their own set of skills associated with them (e.g. experience with major payment gateways, etc) which you might not know to look out for.